# Add an image as an accessory in your UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project, I show a `UITableView`, which currently has text describing a show's name and genre loading from a remote JSON file.

That all works. What I want next is to use the URL from the JSON file and load a thumbnail next to each show.

Using a tutorial, I have added a function to download the remote image with a print to test if it's successful.

```
if let shows_list = json as? NSArray
{
    for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
    {
        if let shows_obj = shows_list[i] as? NSDictionary
        {
            let show_name = shows_obj["show"] as? String
            let show_genre = shows_obj["genre"] as? String
            let show_image = shows_obj["thumbnail"] as? String
            TableData.append(show_name! + " | " + show_genre!)

            let testPictureURL = URL(string: show_image!)!

            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            // Here's the download task where I'm grabbing the image
            let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: testPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
                // The download has finished.
                if let e = error {
                    print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
                } else {
                    // No errors found.
                    if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                        print("Downloaded picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                        if let imageData = data {
                            // Now I know I have data, so I think I can use UIImage to convert it into an image 
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                        } else {
                            print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                    }
                }
            }   
            downloadPicTask.resume()   
        }
```

There are three items in the JSON array, and I get three printed statements that the picture was download: but the image does not appear.

My theory: since this is a table, maybe I have to add this as an accessory, but there isn't an image accessory subclass.

I am new to Swift -- do you have any ideas about how I should append this uploaded image to the table.

Comment: where are you setting the image for the cell ?

Comment: @lionserdar: I thought I was doing it in this code with: let image = UIImage(data: imageData). Maybe I am mistaken? I thought that would draw the data to a UIImage.

Comment: That line only creates an image from the data that you downloaded, you need to set the image for the cell. If you are using default TableViewCell then you can try something like this after your `let image... ` line   `DispatchQueue.main.async { cell.imageView.image = image }` which will basically set the image for that cell.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Since the extract_json is happening after the view did load, the image data isn't accessible it seems earlier in the file where I establish the cell variable. I might need to refactor a lot to make it work. Was hoping I could write directly in the extract_json file but might not be possible, it seems.

Comment: Yes that would be a wise idea!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably being caused by the asynchronous behavior of `URLSession` so when the requested image returns the view is already loaded.

To solve that, you can use a callback, for instance:

```
func myFunction(completion: (returnedImage -> UIIMage) -> Void){
            //...
            let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: testPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
                //...
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                 completion(returnedImage: image)
                //...
            }   
            downloadPicTask.resume()   

        }
}
```

By using a callback, let's say that you have a method called `myFunction(completion:)`, so now when you call the method you can handle whatever comes back from `completion`:

```
myFunction { (image) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async { cell.imageView.image = image }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to be mindful about the cell when the async task finishes to make sure it's the same cell that requested the image and not reused with different data